# using UTF-8 characters in JAVA variable-names

Tags: java, variables, syntax, utf-8, character-encoding

I would like to know that can I use my native language characters (or String) as *JAVA variable names* ?
So, I had tested as below with [Myanmar Unicode](http://my.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aFont).

```
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
    String ဆဆဆ = "မောင်မောင်";
    System.out.println("ကောင်းသောနေ.ပါ " + ဆဆဆ);
}
```

This code show my successful message as **'ကောင်းသောနေ.ပါ မောင်မောင်'**. But in below code with another variable name (*it also my native language String*).....

```
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
    String တက်စတင်း = "မောင်မောင်";
    System.out.println("ကောင်းသောနေ.ပါ " + တက်စတင်း);
}
```

that produce compile time error in my **Ecliplse IDE**.

> *Multiple markers at this line
>       - Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
>       - Got an exception - Unexpected character 0x103a in 
>        identifier*

Any suggestion ? Why would this problem has occured ? Thanks for reading my question patiently.......

Comment: It works for me in Eclipse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java 6 merely supports Unicode 4.0, a quite old version of Unicode which doesn't include Myanmar (or at least only rudimentary). Extended Myanmar support was added to [Unicode 5.1](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode5.1.0/#Myanmar), which is supported in Java 7.

To resolve this issue, install JDK 7 if you haven't already, and configure your Eclipse project to compile as Java 7 (Project->Properties->Java Compiler). Please note that code compiled as Java 7 cannot be run on Java 6 or lower.

Comment: In all honesty, to resolve this issue do not use Myanmar for identifiers :) But +1 for the correct answer.

Comment: I saved the Java file as UTF8 without BOM. When I compile with JDK 6, it complains about the 4154 and 4152 characters. When I compile with JDK 7, a class file is generated successfully. But even with JDK 7, seems it still needs the `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF8` env variable (at least that's what my test shows). So +1 from me too.

Answer (score 4):

Configure charset in your IDE. If you are using Eclipse go to properties and search for charset or encoding. Configure it to be UTF-8 for your java editor.

Comment: There is no way the first code snippet would have worked without a proper charset already in place.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik IIRC Eclipse uses the system's native encoding by default, which may work for the first snippet, but doesn't work for the second one as it includes modifier characters (e.g. the \u103a (်, MYANMAR SIGN ASAT) mentioned in the error message)

Comment: @Njol But the problem is happening at the Java character level and not on the encoding level, just as you have mentioned yourself. The compiler properly decoded the bytes into `\u103a` and is rejecting it.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik correct. I found the actual issue and posted an answer.

Comment: I had configured my IDE >>> workspace to utf-8 and also property of file to utf-8 but still get error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your native language characters as JAVA identifiers if that characters are letters or digits (first character may by a letter only).
To make sure if a character is a letter or digit, use `Character.isLetter` and `Character.isDigit`.

Be careful to use encodings which support your characters. Best choice is UTF-8.

In Strings, you can use any characters.

Comment: The compiler is complaining about 0x103a, which is a zero-space combining character.

Comment: @Njol is တ(MYANMAR LETTER TA) a letter ? Oh really ? It is amazing thing for me. I am a Myanmar citizen but I don't know but you are.....
Thanks a lot for great knowledge for me.

Comment: @Cataclysm I actually only see a weird symbol for that letter (as does Alexei likely), but if Unicode says that it's a letter then Java will do so too and accept it as part of an identifier.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but try setting this OS environment
variable `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` and see if it helps.

```
C:\Work>echo %JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS%
-Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

Answer (score -4):

How about using

Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(myString)

Comment: He is talking about UTF-8 in the code itself, not about supporting UTF-8 data.